# Redirect homepage without query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I am using joomla and i need to put in my htaccess a good redirection.

I need to redirect all this:

```
mysite.com to www.mysite.com  
mysite.com/index.php to www.mysite.com  
www.mysite.com/index.php  
www.mysite.com/    to www.mysite.com  
www.mysite.com/?    to www.mysite.com  
www.mysite.com/?tp=1   to www.mysite.com  
www.mysite.com/?t    to www.mysite.com  
www.mysite.com/?tp  or anything else after ?   to www.mysite.com
```

In my htaccess i have only this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In the future, when you have Joomla questions, please post them at Joomla Stack Exchange.  Did you manage to solve this issue? This page appears abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ty for help but it doesnt work , i copied the code but when i tried to redirect www.mysite.com/? it gave me an error